# Build a database using C# and Entity Framework technology

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Visual Studio 2019, I want to create a database with C# scripting code (it's SQL Server 2017 Express).

But I came across a SqlException. These are some lines of code written to build a database in SQL Server:

```
DataBaseContext DB = new DataBaseContext();
Person oPerson = new Person(1, "Amir");

DB.People.Add(oPerson);
DB.SaveChanges();
```

I expected my database to be built in SQL Server. But in fact, I got an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient. SqlException: 'CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\RahimiMyDB.mdf'.
>
> CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.'

Comment: This question is also already answered here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/localdb-v14-creates-wrong-path-for-mdf-files/199651

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your SQL Server LoaclDB instance with the latest Cumulatitive Update (CU) (this is a known issue with the RTM version)

Comment: this problem solved. I reinstalled the Entity Framework package installed on my program ... it seemed that the package was not installed properly... thank you so much for your time